# Loading 3D studio Max generated animation in DirectX

Tags: animation, directx, 3dsmax, .x

I need to load 3DsMax generated animation in DirectX.File type(.X or any..) is doesn't matters.But the animation should have to played perfectly.
Please if any budy have any sample code or any type of resource or any kind of help will be appreciated.. 
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

New versions of 3DSMax use a filetype where there is no data stored but a sequence of actions (that would be done in 3DSMax).

So there is not and probably won't be a simple conversion to .X...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the tutorial [Working with the DirectX .X File Format and Animation in DirectX 9.0](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/sweet-snippets/working-with-the-directx-x-file-format-and-animation-in-directx-90-r2079). If you have any *specific* questions after that, or particular reasons why that tutorial doesn't apply in your situation, do post again.

Comment: Thank u.. I have already read the article you specified and load some max component in Direct3D surface.I used pandaSoft plugin for conversion.But when i am trying to export animation the object is loaded perfectly but the animation was not played.. only the still object is shown..